# How do i properly test my realm.io implementation in React Native with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, jestjs

I'm quite new to react native and Jest and have so far mostly written tests using the test() method and expect().toBe... or .toEqual. Now since realm works on a document level (as far as i understand) how can i proive sample documents to realm and test what the outcome is ? Is there any documentation that coverst this topic ? I haven't found anything on their official site...

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion on how best to test Realm with jest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing tests, it's important to remember that your goal should not be to test Realm itself, it's to ensure that your components that are dependent on a Realm instance do what you expect. With that said, Jest makes it fairly easy to mock out Realm instances allowing you to validate your application logic.

This GitHub issue thread was helpful for me, hopefully it is for you too: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/370